# Maximum probability to win a number guessing game

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

The following is an interview question from Jane Street.

> A number from $0$ to $1$ is put on a piece of paper. You and person $X$ are playing a game. You must get less than the number on the paper, but above $X$’s guess. You know $X$ chooses to pick a number at random. What is lowest number you can choose to maximize your probability of winning?

An answer given at [glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/A-number-from-0-1-is-put-on-a-piece-of-paper-You-and-Person-X-are-playing-a-game-You-have-to-get-less-than-the-number-on-QTN_112818.htm) seems to be $0.25.$
But the explanation there does not seem rigorous.

Comment: How about the number on the paper? Is that also chosen randomly?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I guess so, that is, the number on paper follows a uniform distribution.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: What happens if person $X$ comes up with a number that exceeds the number on the paper? Do you loose (or win) automatically then?

Answer (score 6):

So you have two independent random variables : $X \sim U[0,1]$ is the guess of $X$, and $P$ is the paper value, also having the same distribution as you mentioned. $X$ is independent of $P$, because $X$ guesses without knowing $P$.

Now, you ask yourself : for which $a$ is $P(X \leq a \leq P)$ maximized? You would pick such an $a$, of course for yourself, so you would have the best probability of winning.

This consists of the two independent events $\{X \leq a\} \cap \{a \leq P\}$. By independence, the probability breaks into $P(X \leq a) \times P(a \leq P)$. The first is $a$ ,the second $1-a$, so the total probability is $a(1-a)$.

This is maximized at $a = 0.5$ (that can be easily seen by $a(1-a) = -(a-\frac 12)^2 + \frac 14$).

Thus, you will most likely choose $0.5$ , and then have a $25%$ chance of winning.

The intuitive reason why this is true, is that if you go too low, say $0.3$, then you risk $X$ getting above you, but if you go too high , say $0.7$, then you risk going above $P$. This balances out at $0.5$, and unfortunately your probability can never be too high because with probability half $X > P$ happens, so in that case you'd lose anyway because of something not in your hands.

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, can you please explain why $P(X \leq a)  = a$ and $P(a \leq P) = (1-a)$? Sorry I am not very good. Many thanks for the help

Comment: @SarahV.P Hey there, I'll need to read the answer, and I'm going for lunch now, so I'll probably respond in like an hour. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I see no worries! :)

Comment: @SarahV.P Let me begin with the setup. So $X$ is a uniform random variable that represents $X$'s guess : that's the hypothesis. Now, for a uniform random variable $U \sim [0,1]$, what is the probability that $U \leq b$ for some $b \in [0,1]$? The answer is that if $U \in [0,b]$ then $U \leq b$, otherwise $U > b$. So, the probability that $U \leq b$ is the probability that $U \in [0,b]$, which we know is equal to $b$ because $U$ is uniform. That's the reason why $P(X \leq a) = a$. For the other one, I'll write a separate comment.

Comment: For the other one, a similar logic applies. The value on the hidden piece of paper is also uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and is called $P$. Now, if $a \leq P$ occurs,then it must happen that $P$ is between $a$ and $1$, that is $P \in [a,1]$. However, the probability of a uniform random variable being in $[a,1]$ is just $1-a$ (assuming that $0 \leq a \leq 1$, which is obvious because $a$ is what you're going to guess at the end) so $P( a \leq P) = 1-a$. If this is not clear, let me know and I'll follow it up with further replies. Thank you for your patience, @SarahV.P.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Sarvesh. why is the probability that $U ∈ [0,b] = b$ because $U$ is uniform? Like I think I am confused with the uniform part. So there is an equally likely chance for $U$ to obtain a value in the range $[0,b]$ and the probability of getting any particular value in that range is $\frac{1}{b-0} = \frac{1}{b} $ right? But this is the PDF, so we want a CDF?

Comment: @SarahV.P Your logic is mostly right (apologies for the very late response, I was on a break) and explains why the *CDF* is the function $F(x) = x$ for $x \in [0,1]$. The probability density (pdf) is just $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere (that's what "uniform" means : a uniform density, right?) So that's right : the probability that $U \in [0,b] = b$ because $U$ is uniform, and its *CDF* formula directly leads to this formula (the pdf as well, but that will require one step more).